# Do NSManagedObjects have file urls?

Tags: core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have an NSManagedObject *obj written to an NSManagedObjectContext. It has key/values which include a "data" key that returns a ~5-10mb size NSData *value. How do i get the url / file path where value is stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Core Data stores everything into a flat persistent store file, usually SQLite. Thus there is no individual file on disk that holds the data you assign to an object.

You can turn on `.allowsExternalBinaryDataStorage` for individual attributes in your model if you wish. This allows Core Data to shove the data into a separate file on disk, *if it sees fit*.

It's important to note that this is for performance optimisation purposes. Core Data does not expose any API to tell you the URL of the file on disk.

Comment: allowsExternalBinaryDataStorage is also useful to reduce the size of the SQLite database file. One additional remark: allowsExternalBinaryDataStorage can also have a negative impact on performance. For example while performing a migration every object in your store is loaded once and, in the easiest case, simply copied to the destination store. So you have a lot of non-linear disk access. If migration is not important for you then this does not really apply since in most situations you can work around problems of this kind easily.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such file url. The way you've designed this managed object and its attributes, the data is stored inside the persistent store along with everything else.